# pandas long to wide: melt + transposing

Tags: pandas, numpy, transpose, melt

I have this dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Status": np.random.choice(["Married", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Widow"], 10000),
               "Genre": np.random.choice(["Masculine", "Masculine", "Masculine", "Femenine"], 10000),
               "Count": 1}).groupby(["Status", "Genre"]).agg("sum").reset_index()
df


    Status  Genre       Count
0   Married Femenine    485
1   Married Masculine   1520
2   Single  Femenine    1493
3   Single  Masculine   4552
4   Widow   Femenine    520
5   Widow   Masculine   1430
```

I'm looking to change it where the columns are the `Genre` values, and an index with the `Status` values, like:

```
            Single  Married  Widow  
Masculine   4552    1520     1430
Femenine    1493    485      520
```

I have tried with a mix of `melt()` and `.T`, but still isn't working. I'm looking for a general approach, as I have 5 `Genre` values and 20 `Status` values.

Comment: `df.pivot('Genre', 'Status', 'Count').rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)`

Comment: or `df.set_index(['Status','Genre']).unstack('Status')`